# split block of records from a text file

Tags: linux, file, text, awk, split

hi guys i have tab delimited file as below

input file

```
6      12312321     123213 123321       
8      afddsf      askakf  asfds          
4      fsdaofs     safjsdf kasdbfksdj        
4      safndsj     skfkds  sfsjl           
4      skjfs       akjsfk  kjdsafk        
9      asnfkjds    kjsdksd ksafnd           
7      12321321    124124 124124         
6      78787878    984929  29232       
8      afddsf      askakf  asfds           
4      fsdaofs     safjsdf kasdbfksdj        
4      safndsj     skfkds  sfsjl          
4      skjfs       akjsfk  kjdsafk          
9      asnfkjds    kjsdksd ksafn           
7      78787878    233232  242214
```

Expected output 1: file1.txt - split first set based on 6 and 7 value in first column

```
6      12312321     123213 123321       
8      afddsf      askakf  asfds          
4      fsdaofs     safjsdf kasdbfksdj        
4      safndsj     skfkds  sfsjl           
4      skjfs       akjsfk  kjdsafk        
9      asnfkjds    kjsdksd ksafnd           
7      12321321    124124 124124
```

Expected output 2: file2.txt

```
6      78787878    984929  29232       
8      afddsf      askakf  asfds           
4      fsdaofs     safjsdf kasdbfksdj        
4      safndsj     skfkds  sfsjl          
4      skjfs       akjsfk  kjdsafk          
9      asnfkjds    kjsdksd ksafn           
7      78787878    233232  242214
```

Expected output 3: file3.txt - split based on 8 and 9 value in first column

```
8      afddsf      askakf  asfds          
4      fsdaofs     safjsdf kasdbfksdj        
4      safndsj     skfkds  sfsjl           
4      skjfs       akjsfk  kjdsafk        
9      asnfkjds    kjsdksd ksafnd
```

Expected output 4: file4.txt

```
8      afddsf      askakf  asfds           
4      fsdaofs     safjsdf kasdbfksdj        
4      safndsj     skfkds  sfsjl          
4      skjfs       akjsfk  kjdsafk          
9      asnfkjds    kjsdksd ksafn
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: want to split the input file into block of record as shown in the expected output. hope its clear.. :-)

Comment: `want to split the input file into block of record as shown in the expected output.` is a statement, not a question. You're expected to show what you've tried so far and ask for help with some aspect of the problem that's causing you problems. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This question is complicated in that we don't know how to create the file names with the correct indexes until after we have finished processing the entire file.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = "\t"
    split("", b67)
    split("", b89)
    i67 = i89 = 0
}

 (i67 in b67)            { b67[i67] = b67[i67] ORS $0 }
 (i67 in b67) && $1 == 7 { ++i67 }
!(i67 in b67) && $1 == 6 { b67[i67] = $0 }

 (i89 in b89)            { b89[i89] = b89[i89] ORS $0 }
 (i89 in b89) && $1 == 9 { ++i89 }
!(i89 in b89) && $1 == 8 { b89[i89] = $0 }

END {
    f = 0
    for (i = 0; i < i67; ++i)
        print b67[i] > "file" ++f ".txt"
    for (i = 0; i < i89; ++i)
        print b89[i] > "file" ++f ".txt"
}
```

There are `()` around the `in` patterns that are not necessary, but were placed in hope that they add clarity.